# 3d object in python with joints

Tags: python, 3d

I got a new project and I dont know how I can start. 
The idea is to create a 3d model with joints and "move" (the angle of the joints) them. The best way would be in python. Is their a libary for something like this?

Also I have to interact with code the joints. So I can give the script different values and the angle of the joints will change.

EDIT: So the libary I was searching for is Pybullet but I got errors by typing `pip install pybullet`. Here the errors: `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybullet` and `error: legacy-install-failure`

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for. Maybe Pybullet? It is an engine that you can use for simulations.

Comment: @MYousefi it is the right libary thx but I got issues with the installation (python: 3.9, pip:22.0.3). Errors: ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybullet & error: legacy-install-failure